# Spotify has stopped working on the latest Ubuntu today, 15.04

Tags: spotify, 15.04

I installed the latest Ubuntu today, 15.04. Spotify has stopped working. How can it be made to work again?

The Unity bar flashes green 4 or 5 times and then stops flashing. There are no error messages. It was installed successfully and played well on 14.10 till the upgrade a few hours ago. It just does not appear on the screen.

Comment: Eliah the Unity bar flashes green 4 or 5 times and then stops flashing. There are no error messages. It was installed successfully & played well on 14.10 till the upgrade a few hours ago. It just does not appear on the screen.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: To the close voters: **Ubuntu 15.04 has been released and is on-topic now...**

Comment: Happened to me as well on 15.04

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a tutorial so you can fix it (beneath reinstalling).
Just execute these two commands, it worked for me:

```
$ wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Link to the source/tutorial:
http://dgzen.pw/2015/04/21/installing-spotify-in-ubuntu-15-04/

Comment: Thanks raverrebel. I followed your steps for the PC &  clvx for my laptop. Both methods work. Thanks all!

Comment: I get 404 not found. Same on all the mirrors at [ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic-updates/amd64/libgcrypt11/download)

Comment: The ubuntu packages work for me. Try: Rightclick the links and choose "Save Target as" or similar (depending on Browser).

Comment: You can use this link to download the file and install from there: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/7110687/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 8):

Before doing the next steps, remove any Spotify ppa's.

Install the Spotify ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" && sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59 && sudo apt-get update -qq && sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Then install the following:

```
wget http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u2_amd64.deb
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This works perfect for me, +1 for actually working (another post I read didn't work, just crashed the login shell)

Comment: It is also the libgcrypt11-dev version in the repositories. That worked for me

Comment: Thanks. How do you 'remove any spotify ppa's'?

Comment: Go to unity dash - ubuntu software center - Edit - Software Sources - Other Software Tab, there you can disable any type of ppa's

Comment: Spotify app is so much better than their webplayer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb
```

source: 
http://www.burakgon.com/2015/04/how-to-fix-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgcrypt-so-11-cannot-open-shared-object-file-error-on-ubuntu-15-04/

Answer (score 2):

Installing libgcrypt11 is said to involve security issues (see [this Spotify forum post](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web/spotify-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgcrypt-so-11/td-p/970485/page/3) which links to [this NVD page](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-5270)).
As mentioned in the Spotify forum post linked above, it's probably better to use the testing version of the Spotify client, available for download on [this repository-origin.spotify.com page](http://repository-origin.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify-client/).
It's not ideal either, but probably the best option.

Comment: I use that version (spotify-client_1.0.19.106.gb8a7150f_amd64.deb  ) with fully updated Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Spotify uses a library called `libgcrypt11` which was replaced in Ubuntu 15.04 by `libgcrypt20`. 
A version of Spotify that doesn't require `libgcrypt11` is available in the testing repository. That is the Spotify that eventually (after it has been tested and any serious bugs have been fixed) will replace the one from the stable repository you have now.

Edit your software sources to change the Spotify repository from stable to testing and then update your Spotify client. 
Some things will be different from before, for better or worse, but at least it starts.